# How to create synthetic data for this case?

Tags: synthetic-data

Some weeks ago, I ran an experiment with 30 participants. For each participant two microphones were recording them while they were reading a phrase in 3 different simulated emotions (Happy, Neutral and Sad). So, I have 180 observations (6 observations for each participant). The data would look something like this:

| Microphone mode | Emotion | Amplitude | ID | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Omni | Happy | 64.1 | 1 | Female |
| Uni | Happy | 60.7 | 1 | Female |
| Omni | Sad | 59.9 | 1 | Female |
| Uni | Sad | 56.4 | 1 | Female |
| Omni | Neutral | 62.2 | 1 | Female |
| Uni | Neutral | 59.7 | 1 | Female |
| … | … | … | … | … |
| Omni | Happy | 62.7 | 30 | Male |
| Uni | Happy | 61.2 | 30 | Male |
| Omni | Sad | 58.8 | 30 | Male |
| Uni | Sad | 57.6 | 30 | Male |
| Omni | Neutral | 60.3 | 30 | Male |
| Uni | Neutral | 59.7 | 30 | Male |

I would like to generate three simulated data sets given this data, each with 300 participants but each with different proportion of microphone modes (i.e., one with 50% omni and 50% uni, another with 30% omni and 70% uni and another with 70% omni and 30% uni).

Does any of you know any easy way to achieve that on R or Python?

I already tried the ‘synthpop’ R package, but it doesn’t seem to allow to define the class proportion (microphone mode) that I would like to generate, and it doesn’t seem to generate new IDs (all the IDs are created between 1 and 30, not sure if that would be a problem or it would be normal. But I didn’t find anyway to control by subjects and at the same time create new subjects).

Comment: A couple of `expand.grid()` commands will populate your independent variables, but that part is purely programming and thus off-topic here. Should your Amplitude depend on the IVs, and if so, how? If not, you can simply fill it with `rnorm()`.

Comment: Also: what do you mean by "30% omni and 70% uni"? Right now, every participant has half of each. Do you want each participant to have about 30%*6=1.8 omni trials (sometimes rounding up, sometimes down, perhaps not getting exactly 30% overall)? Or do you want 30% of participants to have all omni, the others all uni?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes, amplitude depends on the other variables. For example, the happy state usually has higher amplitude than neutral, and sad states, while neutral has higher amplitude than the sad state.

And yes, right. Now each participant has one observation for each microphone mode. What I meant by 70% omni and 30% is to have some participants having all omni and the others all uni.

Comment: OK. Do you then want 3 observations for each ID, one each of happy, sad and neutral?

Comment: Exactly, the idea in that case would be to have 3 observations for each subject, one for happy, one for sad and one for neutral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is R code:

```
emotions <- c("Happy","Sad","Neutral")
```

Set control parameters (I'll assume you want gender balance):

```
n_participants <- 100
proportion_omni <- 0.30
proportion_female <- 0.5
```

Assign your IDs to modes and genders (shuffling both, so we don't have the first $k$ IDs *both* Female and Omni):

```
modes <- structure(
    sample(c(rep("Omni",n_participants*proportion_omni),
        rep("Uni",n_participants*(1-proportion_omni))),
      size=n_participants,replace=FALSE),
    .Names=1:n_participants)
genders <- structure(
    sample(c(rep("Female",n_participants*proportion_female),
        rep("Male",n_participants*(1-proportion_female))),
      size=n_participants,replace=FALSE),
    .Names=1:n_participants)
```

Expand the emotion by ID grid:

```
dataset <- expand.grid(list(Emotion=emotions,ID=1:n_participants))
```

Add the information about modes and genders, as per the settings above:

```
dataset$Microphone_mode <- modes[as.character(dataset$ID)]
dataset$Gender <- genders[as.character(dataset$ID)]
```

Finally, add an amplitude. This simply models an influence of emotion, none of mode or gender. It's not the most elegant way of simulating this, but it's definitely the easiest to understand, and to extend if you want to simulate a more complex influence:

```
dataset$Amplitude <- NA
set.seed(1) # for replicability
index <- dataset$Emotion=="Sad"; dataset$Amplitude[index] <- rnorm(sum(index),60,3) 
index <- dataset$Emotion=="Neutral"; dataset$Amplitude[index] <- rnorm(sum(index),65,3) 
index <- dataset$Emotion=="Happy"; dataset$Amplitude[index] <- rnorm(sum(index),70,3)
```

Result:

```
> head(dataset)
  Emotion ID Microphone_mode Gender Amplitude
1   Happy  1             Uni   Male  71.22821
2     Sad  1             Uni   Male  58.12064
3 Neutral  1             Uni   Male  63.13890
4   Happy  2             Uni Female  75.06662
5     Sad  2             Uni Female  60.55093
6 Neutral  2             Uni Female  65.12635
```